# Wolfram Alpha API giving different data than https://www.wolframalpha.com/

Tags: python, wolframalpha

This is making my head explode. I am making a creating a small Python script the gives me a visualization of the geocentric universe based on the visible placement of the planets on earth. I use Wolfram Alpha API to give me azimuth of each planets on a given date and place. So far so good. When I send a query to the Wolfram Alpha API asking for:

> "azimuth of Venus on 1598-10-01 in Kiruna, Sweden"

and do write the exact same query on

```
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=azimuth+of+Venus+on+1598-10-01+in+Kiruna%2C+Sweden
```

I get fundamental different results. The API gives me: 138∘, 15′, 20′′ and the search on Wolfram Alpha search engine gives me 37∘ 8′, 18′′. Everything is exactly the same.

The Python function I use looks like this:

```
def get_planet_position(celestial_body, date, app_id):
    base_url = "http://api.wolframalpha.com/v2/query"
    query = f"azimuth of {celestial_body} on {date} in Kiruna, Sweden"
    params = {
        "input": query,
        "format": "plaintext",
        "output": "XML",
        "appid": app_id
    }
```

I receive a massive XML but It is easy to find the data in the XML structure. And nowhere in that dataset can you find the result the search engine gives me.

I have also tried to reverse engineer the result and ask wolfram when Venus is in 138∘, 15′, 20′′ but Wolfram does not seem to understand that question.

Is this normal discrepancies when it comes to the Wolfram Alpha API? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also include XML response